# Get database information at runtime

Tags: java, spring

In my web application (spring + tomcat), below is by `applicationContext.xml`. All the database information (`username`, `password`) is currently directly embedded. But now in our application, the server forks a new `JVM` instance and this new `JVM` instance needs to communicate with the same database.

> ```
> <bean id="meetingDBSource"
>       class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
>       destroy-method="close" p:initialSize="10" p:maxActive="50" p:minIdle="5"
>       p:maxIdle="35" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>       p:url="jdbc:mysql://10.0.1.100/warehouse_mon?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;"
>       p:username="user" p:password="pass" p:testOnBorrow="true"
>       p:validationQuery="SELECT 1" />> 
>
> <bean id="appDB" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
>     <property name="dataSource">
>         <ref bean="meetingDBSource" />
>     </property>
> </bean>
> ```

So I wish to pass the required information as arguments while launching it. Now what is the dignified way of getting this database information?

Initially in my `applicationContext.xml`, I made a map and inserted all the db information in the map. Using Spring special expressions, I was obtaining the values and then using them for `BasicDataSource` initialization. And in my code, using dependency injection I obtained access to this map and then obtained information.

But I guess there should be a more standard factory way of doing it. (Or probably using `context-param` and if so, how?)

Comment: are you using jpa or may be hibernate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it like this.

I have a database.properties file like this.

```
db.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.connectionUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
db.username=test
db.password=testpass
sql.use.db.data=false
sql.use.db.test.data=false
```

Then in applicationContext.xml I will configure

```
<!--property place holder bean -->
<bean id="propertyPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>

            <value>classpath:/properties/database.properties</value>                
        </list>
    </property>
```

Then  datasource is configured like this

```
<!-- data source bean-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.connectionUrl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

You can use @Value annotation to access the properties in that file.

```
@Value("${sql.use.db.data}")
private String use_data;
```